# start-stop-daemon keeps editing my shebang making it impossible to run

Tags: command-line, services

`start-stop-daemon --name flaskserver --start --chuid root --exec /root/worker/start.sh`

start.sh clearly has this line `#!/usr/bin` but after I run above, it results in `!/usr/bin` and of course it will complain that it can't run it due to `exec format error`

why is it doing this and how can I make it run the `.sh` without touching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the command as follows:

```
start-stop-daemon --name flaskserver --start --chuid root --exec /bin/bash /root/worker/start.sh
```

or

```
start-stop-daemon --name flaskserver --start --chuid root --exec /root/worker/start
```

Comment: what also worked was renaming start.sh to start. and it stopped trying to edit the file.